# Does the second text "Shops selling everything from..." mean the same as "Shops that sell everything from..."

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

So, I was reading an article today, and I came across a sentence that went

> Keep walking, and you will find yourself walking past shops that **sell** everything, from steel trunks to conch shells.

And I was wondering, if I changed the sentence to

> Keep walking, and you will find yourself walking past shops **selling** everything, from steel trunks to conch shells.

would it mean the same as the original sentence? Or would there be a difference in the meaning?

Comment: @Stephie, I made a mistake typing that 2nd version in the title.
Does everything seem fine now?

Comment: I'm not really that good with grammar, or its technicalities for that matter, i just come across certain sentences that gain my interest and i just post them here as questions. xD

Two topics that really interest me are dropping out prepositions, and tenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They have the same meaning.**

"Shops that sell everything" is describing the shops. 'They sell everything.'

"Shops selling everything" is having the shops perform an action. 'They are currently selling everything'

The only difference is that the second sentence seem to imply that they are currently selling, although few people would assume that. But generally either one is acceptable. Most speakers would assume "currently" means when they are open.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are equivalent in meaning.

The argument could be made by pendants that this only holds if the shops are currently engaged in business, but as a native speaker it would be a complete toss up which version I used, even if I was speaking at the dead of night, about shops that were closed.